# rust file in package cannot find package name when using 'use extern PACKAGE_NAME'

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── model.rs
│   └── lib.rs
└── examples
    └── client.rs
```

What my cargo.toml looks like:

```
[package]
name = "swagger_client"
version = "1.0.0"
authors = []
description = "example test"
```

In client.rs I try to say:

```
extern crate swagger_client;

use swagger_client::{testing_struct,alpha,beta};
```

However "extern crate swagger_client;" causes an error.

```
src/lib.rs
can't find crate for `swagger_client`

can't find crate rustc(E0463)
client.rs(3, 1): can't find crate
```

Comment: What command are you running to get the error? `cargo run --example client`?

Comment: I just use "cargo build. I have a lot of errors and I just noticed it says: "could not compile swagger_client". Do you think the fact that it hasn't been compiled is causing the issue?

Comment: the cannot find crate error is only showing up on the visual studio code editor not on the terminal I use to compile the code.

Comment: `only showing up on the visual studio code` may just be what happens with `examples` when open in VSCode, hard to say. Sounds like you need to get `cargo build` working first, so this question seems unanswerable as-is. I'd remove the example, get it building, and then add it back.

Comment: @loganfsmyth when it was compiled without warnings the cannot find crate warning disappeared. thanks for taking the time to answer